# Standard way to say "use of smth."

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

For example

> He did not like the use of pesticides, the name of chemicals used to kill bugs on the crops

My first thought is to combine it into a compound word, like

> Er mochte nicht der Pflanzenschutzmittelgebrauch, die Name der Chemikalien ist, die benutzt werden, Insekten auf Pflanzen zu töten.

(let me know if there's a better way to phrase that sentence I feel it's kind of clunky)

The problem here is that I'm not sure you're allowed to refer to part of a word in a relative clause, because the "die" in "die Name..." refers to just "Pflanzenschutzmittel", not the entire "Pflanzenschutzmittelgebrauch"

The other way I'd think of phrasing this is Gebrauch+gen or Gebrauch+von, like

> Er mochte nicht der Gebrauch des/von Pflanzenschutzmittel(s), die Name der Chemikalien ist, die benutzt werden, Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten.

What is the preferred way to say something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have the wrong translation for pesticides. The right one would be `Pestizide`. `Pflanzenschutzmittel` encompass pesticides, herbicides, and fungicides.

Next is the article in the sub clause. I don't know whether there is a rule, but you can omit the article of the reference noun. But you have to use the article of the following noun.

In your translation you also forgot `um`. It is a conjunction that describes a purpose.

Furthermore, the construct you used, is the wrong order. Your main clause should be

> Er mochte den Pestizidgebrauch nicht.

`mögen` calls for the accusative.

And I don't know why you put a `ist` after `Chemikalien` but it is wrong.

So a correct translation would be:

> Er mochte den Pestizidgebrauch, der Name der Chemikalien, die benutzt werden, um Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten, nicht.

But like you said, this is a bit unclear what the name is. If you want to leave the main clause, you could say this:

> Er mochte den Pestizidgebrauch, den Gebrauch von Chemikalien, die benutzt werden, um Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten, nicht.

But the idea behind your second translation is also correct.

We only have to know if he disliked the usage of one particular pesticide, multiple particular pesticides or pesticides in general. If it is one particular pesticide, the correct translation is `des Pestizids`. If it is multiple particular ones, the translation is `der Pestizide`. Both of these are genitive.

If it is pesticides in general, the correct translation is `Pestiziden`.

You can also use `von + Akkusativ` if you want to express the first two cases. then you'd use `von dem Pestizid` for one particular and `von den Pestiziden` for multiple particular.

So a correct translation according to the second idea would be:

> Er mochte den Gebrauch von Pestiziden, der Name der Chemikalien, die benutzt werden, um Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten, nicht.

## Thanks to tofro:

`Gebrauch` is mainly used on something that is used on somebody.

For everything else, `die Anwendung` respectively `anwenden` should be used. So the better translations would be

> Er mochte die Pestizidanwendung, der Name der Chemikalien, die benutzt werden, um Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten, nicht.

or

> Er mochte die Anwendung von Pestiziden, der Name der Chemikalien, die benutzt werden, um Insekten an Pflanzen zu töten nicht.

Comment: "Gebrauch" is rarely used for pesticides. "Anwendung" would be a better and more common translation. "Gebrauch" is only commonly used for things you use for/on yourself - "Betäubungsmittelgebrauch"

Comment: @tofro fair point. As soon as I have some free time, I'll incorporate that into my answer.